# Import cv2 error but opencv-python is already installed

Tags: python, pip, opencv

I've been trying to make a project with opencv, so I followed the YouTube video (It's in python), the video told me to go to cmd (win10) and use the command "pip install opencv-python" so that I can use the command import cv2. But the problem is after I did everything it still gave me an error.

I've done some research on it and nothing seem to work. I tried restarting my laptop or reinstall opencv, but nothing works for me. I'm thinking maybe it's because the PATH was wrong so it couldn't access it? But I've never worked with these before so I don't know what I'm supposed to do. I've seen some people with the same problem but the solution doesn't seem to work.

I'm using:
python 3.10.8
windows 10
IDLE Shell 3.10.1

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: YouTube is not the most trustworthy site for Python/OpenCV demos. I would suggest you search this forum or Google for examples.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages.  Please post your code and error messages using the formatting controls provided.

Comment: do you have multiple pythons or virtual environments? or do you have multiple conflicting packages? run `pip list`

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Try installing with pip3

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: It's already installed, is it because of PATH?

this is what came up i typed the command
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\dennis\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (4.6.0.66)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\users\dennis\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.23.4)

Comment: You got me there. Try to answer the comments the users put on your question so they might help you. 

In case, I don't use idle shell, but anaconda/Jupyter lab